# Style HTML form with background image for all browsers

Tags: html, css, image

I'm working on creating an HTML form that has an image in the background. Currently, it only lines up correctly in certain browsers, and in others it is only a few pixels off.

I thought that the following CSS would solve my problem, it helped, but it did not fix the problem.

```
input {
width: 105px;    
-webkit-box-sizing: border-box; /* Safari/Chrome, other WebKit */    
-moz-box-sizing: border-box;    /* Firefox, other Gecko */    
box-sizing: border-box;         /* Opera/IE 8+ */ 
}
```

Additionally, all the form inputs are floated and positioned with margins.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the image is a static size, you might consider setting it as the background of a container with `position:relative;` and then use `position:absolute;` with `top:`, `left:`, `right:` and `bottom:` for positioning and sizing.

Comment: I changed to this method of styling, but the form is still off in Internet Explorer and FireFox, it looks great in Chrome

Comment: Got it working correctly in FireFox with CSS browser selection ".gecko #mc-embedded-subscribe"

Answer (score 1):

```
.searchBox{
  background-image:url('images/magnifying-glass.gif');
  background-repeat:no-repeat;
  padding-left:20px;
}
```

Now, we simply assign our input tag to the CSS class "searchBox":

```
<input type="text" name="search" class="searchBox">
```

Comment: This was not what I was looking for, I have the image in the background already, the form elements are just positioning differently in different browsers. And by form background I meant a background image that is behind multiple inputs, not an icon that is in the actual input field.